# Netbeans 8 module dependencies

Tags: php, netbeans, archlinux

Just upgraded to netbeans 8.
Starting it result:

```
Warning - could not install some modules: 
Bootstrap - The module Utilities API was requested in version >= 8.37 but only 8.33.2 was     found. 
Another module could not be installed due to the above problems.
```

How to found out which module is the depending one? Or how to update manually to 8.37?
I'm using netbeans for php development, no need for java support...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just rename netbeans config file. File is located at `{netbeans-installation-dir}/etc/netbeans.conf`